# How to fix placement of layers in Apple Preview (works in Adobe Reader and others)

Tags: layers, portability, ocgx2, ocgx

I am trying to create an interactive PDF where one can switch between a color and a grayscale image using the `ocgx2` package. It works on Adobe (with interactive element), and displays fine in most other viewers (mostly without the interactivity, but displays fine). Here is the minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[h]
    \switchocg{nobw bw}{%
        \begin{ocg}{blackandwhite}{bw}{off}
            \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_bw.png}
        \end{ocg}%
        \hspace*{-\textwidth}
        \begin{ocg}{colored}{nobw}{on}
            \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_col.png}
        \end{ocg}%
    }
    \caption{There it is!}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

With these images:

[image: colored image]
[image: grayscale image]

Here's what it looks in most viewers including Adobe Reader:

[image: adobe result]

And here's what I get in Apple Preview:

[image]

I need this to work in any viewer, at least showing the colored version non-interactively and having the interactive version available in Adobe Reader. Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: I suspect that this is a bug in the underlying software. Do you get the same results with all of pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and luaLaTeX?

Comment: Same behavior with luaLaTeX, but XeLatex did the job! Thanks so much! If you happen to know how get this done with pdflatex, that would be even better!

Comment: That's interesting. As ocgx2 maintainer I'd like to dig a bit deeper, but unfortunately I don't own a Mac to run tests myself. So, what happens if the OCG-related lines (`\switchocg`, `ocg` environment) are commented out. Do the images appear at the right place? Some line endings have to be commented out to exactly position the images:

Comment: `\begin{figure}[h]
%    \switchocg{nobw bw}{%
%        \begin{ocg}{blackandwhite}{bw}{off}
            \noindent%
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_bw.png}%
%        \end{ocg}%
        \hspace*{-\textwidth}%
%        \begin{ocg}{colored}{nobw}{on}
            \noindent%
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image_col.png}%
%        \end{ocg}%
%    }
    \caption{There it is!}
\end{figure}`

Comment: yes, if I comment them out, I get the "Adobe Reader"-look from above also in Preview.

Comment: Thanks, and what if only `\switchocg{nobw bw}{` and the closing `}` are commented out?

Comment: Then I still get the displaced look in preview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134789/discussion-between-alexg-and-john-smith).